# Start docker container from another application in another docker container

Tags: docker

We have an existing java application which exposes a REST API. When it receives a http request, it starts another java process using the Runtime.getRuntime().exec.

We are in the process of migrating this application to docker and we would like to separate these services, the REST application in 1 container and the other component in another container.

Is there any way, that the REST application can start the other application in another docker container?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can programmatically spawn a docker container.
Docker Remote API will allow you to do that. You can either use http client library to invoke the remote APIs or you can use java docker client libraries to do the same.

Here is the relevant docker documentation:

Remote API: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/
Libraries: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/remote_api_client_libraries/