# How do I start a Docker container from a Java project inside another container

Tags: java, docker, api

I have a Java project that uses Spring Boot, that I have inside a Docker container. I want it to start another container on a specific port when it is invoked.

I can't seem to figure out how, I know the Docker engine has an API that I can interact with, but how do I do that?

Comment: It's possible, but quite unusual. More commonly, an external tool on top of Docker, such as Docker Compose, is used to start and connect multiple containers together.

Comment: yea i know how to use docker compose, my project is supposed to create new containers on the fly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581644/start-docker-container-from-another-application-in-another-docker-container

Comment: Just a concern: from a security point of view this is tricky as the container that has the ability to spawn other containers will have an effective root access (e.g. spawn a container that mounts '/' of the host and does some nasties).